# Equivalence of two presentations for a quotient of the braid group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, braid-groups

I'm considering two presentations for quotients of the 3-strand braid group $B_3$ that I believe should be equivalent (i.e. yield the same quotient). There is an integer parameter $d \ge 7$ involved, and I'll write $\Delta^2 = (\sigma_1\sigma_2)^3$ for the full twist braid. Then we have two quotient groups given by the presentations
$$Q_1 = \langle \sigma_1, \sigma_2 \mid \sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1 = \sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2, \sigma_1^d = \sigma_2^d = 1,  (\Delta^2)^\ell = 1\rangle$$
where $\ell = 2d/\gcd(12,d+6)$ and
$$Q_2 = \langle \sigma_1, \sigma_2 \mid \sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1 = \sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2, \sigma_1^d = \sigma_2^d = 1,  (\sigma_1^{-2}\Delta^2)^m = 1\rangle$$
where $m=2d/\gcd(4,d+2)$. Can anyone help elucidate whether these groups are in fact isomorphic?

---

Here's what I have so far. First, an observation relating the powers $\ell$ and $m$, proof left to the reader.

**Lemma** $m/\ell = 3$ when $3 \mid d$ and $m/\ell = 1$ otherwise.

Now given the typical braid relation and the relations $\sigma_1^d = \sigma_2^d=1$, we want to show that the remaining relations are equivalent.

**Case 1: $3 \not\mid d$**. Then $m=\ell$ and $\ell = 2d/1, 2d/2,$ or $2d/4$. Notice then that $\sigma_1^{-2\ell}=1$. Now one finds
$$(\sigma_1^{-2}\Delta^2)^m = (\sigma_1^{-2}\Delta^2)^\ell = \sigma_1^{-2\ell} (\Delta^2)^\ell = (\Delta^2)^\ell.$$ Thus $(\sigma_1^{-2}\Delta^2)^m=1$ if and only if $(\Delta^2)^\ell=1$.

**Case 2: $3 \mid d$**. Then $m=3\ell$ and $\ell=2d/12,2d/6,$ or $2d/3$. Notice now that $\sigma_1^{-6\ell}=1$. Now one finds
$$(\sigma_1^{-2}\Delta^2)^m = (\sigma_1^{-2}\Delta^2)^{3\ell} = \sigma_1^{-6\ell} (\Delta^2)^{3\ell} = (\Delta^2)^{3\ell}.$$ If $\Delta^2$ has order $\ell$, then $(\sigma_1^{-2}\Delta^2)$ has order $m$. **But the converse does not seem to follow.**

Can anyone clear up this last remaining hole in the argument?

Comment: If you haven't already, try experimenting in GAP. I have [`TzGoGo`](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap48.html) in mind. You can get it to output its Tietze transformations as it goes.

Comment: If I have typed in the presentations correctly, then they are not isomorphic for $d=6$. They have different numbers of conjugacy classes of subgroups of index at most $10$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I should have mentioned (and now have have edited) that I actually only want values of $d$ at least 7.

Comment: They are not isomorphic for $d=12$ for the same reason. They seem to be isomorphic when $3$ does not divide $d$. I am not sure about $d=9$.

Comment: But I can give it a go myself for higher values of $d$. Really interesting, thanks!